# android - how to find the name of the main activity of an application?

Tags: android, android-activity

For example, I want to start Gmail in code/command line, but I don't know its main activity name.

```
am start -n com.google.android.gm/.XXXXX
```

It's available through decompiling the apk, but it's difficult.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can plug your phone into the computer and look at the DDMS log, application launches are printed there, e.g:

```
05-11 09:19:15.725: INFO/ActivityManager(96): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x2000000 cmp=com.google.android.gm/.ConversationListActivity bnds=[125,410][235,540] } from pid 2457
```

So, `com.google.android.gm/.ConversationListActivity`, would seem like the right choice, at least, that's what the icon seems to launch.

Answer (score 22):

This can be found in the application's manifest.

The main activity is the `activity` with the `intent-filter` whose name is `android.intent.action.MAIN`.

Answer (score 6):

Step1: Start "adb logcat" in command prompt.

Step2: Open the app (either in emulator or real device)
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to know it's name, instead you should use [implicit intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)
and specify action along with type and some extras, for example

```
            final Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("message/rfc822");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Some subject");
```

System will search for components available to run this intent.

Answer (score 4):

Just go to Android package n open Android Manifest File n check out this activity element

```
<activity>
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

In continuation to the previous answers above I'd like to extend it to what helped me by combining it.

I searched the `AndroidManifest.xml` file for `android.intent.action.MAIN` (Tony the pony) and used the name attribute in the following command run on the actual device and executed the app:

```
$ adb logcat | grep "com.some.interesting.app"
10-23 14:53:34.795 10568 12967 W RecentsModel: getRunningTask   taskInfo=TaskInfo{userId=0 taskId=286 displayId=0 isRunning=true baseIntent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.some.app/com.some.interesting.app.splash.SplashActivity } baseActivity=ComponentInfo{com.some.app/com.some.interesting.app.splash.SplashActivity} topActivity=ComponentInfo{com.some.app/com.some.interesting.app.main.MainActivity} origActivity=ComponentInfo{com.some.app/com.some.interesting.app.splash.SplashActivity} realActivity=ComponentInfo{com.some.app/com.some.interesting.app.main.MainActivity} numActivities=1 lastActiveTime=3026326848 supportsSplitScreenMultiWindow=true supportsMultiWindow=true resizeMode=2 isResizeable=true token=WCT{android.window.IWindowContainerToken$Stub$Proxy@feba6cc} topActivityType=1 pictureInPictureParams=PictureInPictureParams( aspectRatio=null sourceRectHint=null hasSetActions=false isAutoPipEnabled=false isSeamlessResizeEnabled=true) displayCutoutSafeInsets=Rect(0, 94 - 0, 0) topActivityInfo=ActivityInfo{1f05d15 com.some.interesting.app.splash.SplashActivity} launchCookies=[] positionInParent=Point(0, 0) parentTaskId=-1 isFocused=false isVisible=true topActivityInSizeCompat=false locusId= null windowMode=0}
10-23 14:53:34.958 10568 10568 D RecentsImpl: mActivityStateObserver com.some.interesting.app.main.MainActivity
10-23 14:53:34.958 10568 10568 W RecentsImpl: onResumed className=com.some.interesting.app.main.MainActivity   mIsInAnotherPro=false   isKeyguardLocked=false
```

from the above output the `cmp=com.some.app/com.some.interesting.app.splash.SplashActivity` is actually what we're lookingn for.

So if you execute:

```
$ am start com.some.app/com.some.interesting.app.splash.SplashActivity
```

or

```
$ am start com.some.app/com.some.interesting.app.main.MainActivity
```

The app will execute in the device.