# Automate iOS / Android Device to View E-mails

Tags: java, android, ios, appium

So i am attempting to Automate verification of an automatically generated e-mail. I am fairly new to appium, and was wondering if there is a way that i could automate the device to open the emails , allowing me to automate steps to open the relevant email and capture the text?

Cheers.

Comment: add exactly code related issue here....

Comment: this is a good place to start - https://github.com/appium/java-client
Feel free to ask if you have any specific issue with coding

Answer (score 0):

For Android, all you need is the .apk (or optionally corresponding activities) of the email app you wish to open.

The default email app is com.android.email and can be extracted via instructions on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18003462/5348032), and if you need it, you can find the activities several [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964735/android-how-to-find-the-name-of-the-main-activity-of-an-application)

If you want to use a different email app, you'll simply use the appropriate package name in step 2 of the .apk extraction instructions.

Then it's as simple as plugging the appropriate values in for the desiredCapabilities as you would any other app. Ex: `caps.setCapability("app", "/path/to/email.apk")`