# How do I get the main Activity name which is required to get the componentName of any app for hiding it from launcher

Tags: android, android-manifest

```
ActivityInfo[] list
    = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName()).activities;
```

This gives me the list of all `Activitie`s, but how to find out which activity is the main `Activity`?

---

I guess Im making a mistake,Im new to android, please correct me

```
       PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
       Intent intent = p.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.launcherhiddenapp");
       ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, String.valueOf(intent));
       p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, 
       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

This is not working, my app is visible in launcher and I can launch it as asusually

This is my code after I used intent

```
       PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
       Intent intent = p.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName());
       ComponentName componentName = new 
       ComponentName(this,String.valueOf(intent));
       p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, 
       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 
       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

It is still not working, app is visible in launcher, Please help me anyone

Comment: When you say "main Activity", do you mean the launcher activity?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android - how to find the name of the main activity of an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964735/android-how-to-find-the-name-of-the-main-activity-of-an-application)

Comment: Im making an app where it gets list of installed apps with checkboxes, if user clicks a checkbox, that particular app has to hide from launcher in non rooted mobile, so i need the ComponentName of that app, it has 2 parameters package name and mainactivity class name, we can get the package name of any other app in my app, using ActivityInfo I can get the list of all activities of other app, but how do I find out the mainactivity name? @Ajeeli

Comment: yes the first activity that opens up as application start @Ajeeli

Comment: Replace "com.example.launcherhiddenapp" with "packageName"

Comment: Intent intent = p.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)

Comment: How can system recognise that packageName, it says cannot resolve symbol packageName! @Ajeeli

Comment: Intent intent = p.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName())

Comment: @Ajeeli, mam "com.example.launcherhiddenapp" is my package name, To check out whether it works fine or not, Im trying to hardcode the package name. But in my actual app, I have to have the package name of the other apps in launcher which is to be hidden

Comment: I think you need to edit your original question to be more clear and obvious about what you actually need.

Comment: yes mam sorry about that I have modified my question accordingly, please help me @Ajeeli

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
PacketManager manager = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName());
```

This should give you the full package name of the main activity

Comment: No its not working,  PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
           ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, com.example.launcherhiddenapp.MainActivity.class);
           p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP); In this code Im trying to hide my own app icon in launcher, I can get the component name, for other apps how will I get the component name. ComponentName requires 2 things, a packagename which we can get, other is Mainactivity.class name which is difficult to get.How will I get this.