# How to handle permissions in android app for Robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework, android-permissions, appium-android

How to handle permissions in android app using Appium library for Robot framework?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the application using the following Key Word from Appium Library

`Open Application    http://localhost:4723/wd/hub   app= <path to apk>    platformName=Android   appPackage=<appPackage>   appActivity=<appActivity>   automationName=UiAutomator2   autoGrantPermissions=true   newCommandTimeout=10000`

Here is a link explaining how to get apk activity [how to get apk activiy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964735/android-how-to-find-the-name-of-the-main-activity-of-an-application)